# How to install and setup graylog-server and graylog-web on Ubuntu from repository?

Tags: 14.04, log

I am trying to setup [graylog](https://www.graylog.org/) on Ubuntu 14.04. I tried to find out installation steps on internet I found few links. but their method of installation is manual I mean installation from the source. and I don't want to follow installation from source because posts are old, some are talking about graylog2(I could not found difference between normal graylog and graylog2), their source package is old so there configuration files are not matching with latest configuration files.

so I decided to setup latest greylog from official documentation at http://docs.graylog.org/en/1.0/pages/installation.html#ubuntu-14-04

I have installed latest [mongodb](https://www.mongodb.org/) and [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch).
after that I followed steps to install graylog-server and graylog-web from official documentation.

```
$ wget https://packages.graylog2.org/repo/packages/graylog-1.0-repository-ubuntu14.04_latest.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i graylog-1.0-repository-ubuntu14.04_latest.deb
$ sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install graylog-server graylog-web
```

I am able to see configuration files after installation

```
/etc/graylog/server/server.conf
/etc/graylog/web/web.conf
```

I am able to see other files at

```
/usr/share/graylog-server
/usr/share/graylog-server/bin
/usr/share/graylog-server/graylog.jar
/usr/share/graylog-web
/usr/share/graylog-web/bin/
/usr/share/graylog-web/conf
```

I configured `/etc/graylog/server/server.conf` and `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` with help of https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-graylog2-and-centralize-logs-on-ubuntu-14-04 and able to run graylog-server by running

```
java -jar /usr/share/graylog-server/graylog.jar server
```

this shows me

```
Started REST API at <http://127.0.0.1:12900/
Graylog server up and running.
```

After that I am not understanding how to setup graylog-server and graylog-web properly because these steps are not complete. I will appreciate if someone could give clean steps for proper setup. thanks in advance

Comment: please someone add tag `graylog` to my post

Comment: Open the URL http://127.0.0.1:12900/ in your browser.

Comment: @A.B. its showing `{"type":"ApiError","message":"HTTP 404 Not Found"}`

Comment: You've completed all the steps of the guide?

Comment: no, I completed till what I have mentioned in post because author is setting up from source and I am setting up from repository

Answer (score 1):

I am writing steps to setup `graylog-server` and `graylog-web` from repository. graylog-web is webbased frontend to graylog.

1. [mongodb](https://www.mongodb.org/) and [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) are the dependencies so we have to install these first.
2. now configure elasticsearch e.g. edit `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`
   sample setting is
   `cluster.name: graylog-production`
   `network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0`
   `discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false`
   `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["127.0.0.1:9300"]`
   `script.disable_dynamic: true`
3. now restart elasticsearch by `sudo service elasticsearch restart`
4. Now install graylog-server and graylog-web
   first setup graylog repository
   `$ wget https://packages.graylog2.org/repo/packages/graylog-1.0-repository-ubuntu14.04_latest.deb`
   `$ sudo dpkg -i graylog-1.0-repository-ubuntu14.04_latest.deb`
   `$ sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https`
   `$ sudo apt-get update`
   now we can install graylog-server and graylog-web by `apt-get`
   `$ sudo apt-get install graylog-server graylog-web`
5. Now graylog-server has installed, we need to configure setting e.g. edit file `/etc/graylog/server/server.conf`
   follow https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-graylog2-and-centralize-logs-on-ubuntu-14-04 and http://docs.graylog.org/en/1.0/pages/installation.html#ubuntu-14-04 for settings.
   see sample setting file at http://paste.ubuntu.com/12426568/
6. check if graylog-server is running or not
   `java -jar /usr/share/graylog-server/graylog.jar server`
   if its running then you will see lines
   `Started REST API at <http://127.0.0.1:12900/`
   `Graylog server up and running.`
7. Now if graylog-server is running fine then you re ready to setup graylog-web. we have already installed it so now copy `/etc/graylog/web/web.conf` to `/usr/share/graylog-web/conf/web.conf` and give values
   `graylog2-server.uris="http://127.0.0.1:12900/"` and set `application.secret`
8. we are done now, so lets start graylog-web
   `sudo /usr/share/graylog-web/bin/graylog-web-interface` or by `sudo start graylog-web`
9. check by opening `http://localhost:9000`

Answer (score 0):

install Graylog2 Server v0.20.2 in /opt. First, download the Graylog2 archive to /opt with this command:

```
cd /opt; sudo wget https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog2server/releases/download/0.20.2/graylog2server-0.20.2.tgz 
sudo tar xvf graylog2-server-0.20.2.tgz sudo ln -sgraylog2-server-0.20.2 graylog2-server 
sudo cp /opt/graylog2-server/graylog2.conf.example /etc/graylog2.conf sudo apt-get install pwgen SECRET=$(pwgen -s 96 1) 

sudo -E sed -i -e 's/password_secret =.*/password_secret = '$SECRET'/' /etc/graylog2.conf
```

Full tutorial at [allubuntu.com](http://allubuntu.com/how-to-install-graylog2-and-centralize-logs-on-ubuntu/)